# How to convert column values into column headers in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i'm trying to pivot a df. I would like to convert column values to row headers. Thanks in advance.

How can I change this:

```
name
0   countryCode
1   vatNumber
2   requestDate
3   valid
4   name
5   address
```

to this in python?

```
name  countryCode  vatNumber requestDate valid name address
0
```

Comment: can't you use a transpose? `df.T`? what is `print(df.columns)`

Comment: Hi anky, yes you are right.

did a df.transpose() and it worked, however they are still not headers.



0               1              2                     3                        4              5
name countryCode vatNumber requestDate valid name address`

Comment: what is `print(df.columns)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, df.T as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['countryCode', 'vatNumber','requestDate', 'valid', 'name', 'address']})

df = df.T
df

             0        1          2            3          4        5
name    countryCode vatNumber   requestDate valid      name    address

df.columns = df.values[0]
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
df


    countryCode vatNumber   requestDate valid   name    address
0   countryCode vatNumber   requestDate valid   name    address
```

Then replace all non null values with np.nan:

```
df[df.notna()] = np.nan
df
countryCode vatNumber   requestDate valid   name    address
0   NaN        NaN          NaN       NaN   NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Hi Mohit, thanks for the prompt reply. Can I also remove index 0 or should this be filled?

Comment: HI @mrichman I don't think you can remove the index. Do you want a different index?

Comment: I'm planning to do a loop on an API and would like to append the right values to the right column names. Is this the way to go? Thanks in advance.